# Iterate over a list of directories in Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a way to iterate over a list of directories in Windows command prompt?

I have a bunch of folders that each contain SQL dump files. The number of folders grows as data updates come in, and so every once in a while I need to process the latest X number of folders, where X is variable and doesn't include every subfolder in the root folder. E.g. the directory structure looks like this:

```
root/
+--folder1/
|  +--<bunch of files>
+--folder2/
|  +--<bunch of files>
+--folder3/
   +--<bunch of files>
```

And say in this case I want to process all files in folder 2 and 3, but not folder 1. I currently do this with code like:

```
# starting in root/
cd folder2
for /f %f in ('dir /b *.sql') do mysql < %f
cd ..

cd folder3
for /f %f in ('dir /b *.sql') do mysql < %f
cd ..
```

How can i instead do something like this?:

```
for x in ('folder1', 'folder2') do (
  cd %x
  for /f %f in ('dir /b *.sql') do mysql < %f
  cd ..
)
```

I see that there are some other slightly related questions, but just to be clear, I *don't* want to loop through all subdirectories in a folder. I would simple like to manually specify a list of folders to loop through.

Comment: Does it specifically have to be CMD.EXE? This is easy in Powershell.

Comment: [for /d - Loop through directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Comment: FOR /D [/r] %%parameter IN (folder_set) DO command`

Comment: @CBHacking, I guess no. I'm generally not familiar with Windows tools so I don't have a preference.

Comment: `powershell.exe` and `cmd.exe` are the two CLI shell programs that come with modern Windows. Powershell (which isn't actually Windows-only) is .NET based, offers modern shell features, and a powerful and relatively friendly object-oriented scripting language (with an extremely extensive library, since it can directly use the .NET framework and anything written on top of it). It supports features such as `foreach` loops, which seems to be what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a little known standard command for that: `forfiles`.

See the output of `forfiles /?` for more information and some examples how to use it.
You can do the same thing with a `for` construct, but for something like this `forfiles` is easier to use.
And you can also have it work on ONLY files younger (or older) than a specified date, which is especially useful to cleanup old logfiles.

Comment: Oh this is cool. Minor hiccup, is there any way to influence the order of files? They should be run in an order that matches file names, but the default order is sometimes not the same. I've gotten to `for /S /M files *.sql /D [date] /C "cmd /c echo @file" | sort` and that looks good, but don't know how to iterate over the file names after that.

Comment: @andybega Unfortunately FOR and FORFILES process files in whatever order as found in the directory. In that case you are on the right track with your sort pipeline. Just redirect the output of sort to a temp-file and then use another FOR to parse the content of that file. (There are other ways but this would probably be the easiest.)